# Ideas for generating MAR with a logistic or nonparametric algorithm?

Tags: r, r-mice

I have simulated data that I want to ampute.

I first went to the mice package to use their ampute function. But I noticed that the algorithm behind generating MAR data is with linear regression and there do not appear to be ways to generate my MAR data with something like a logit. It would be ideal if the MAR process is nonparametric, but I first wanted to see what is out there for functions or approaches to generating MAR without an OLS.

Any ideas?

Comment: Asking for package recommendations is off-topic. I'd suggest checking out the curated [CRAN task view for missing data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MissingData.html). The Multiple Imputation section mentions many packages including mice, many of which are not based on OLS.

Comment: In addition to `mice`, the Task View mentions `simFrame` and `simglm` for amputation.

Comment: Gotcha. Okay thanks. I'll check these out. Appreciate it.